# Android Back button return previous, but exit the app

Tags: android, fragment, back-button

Override this function, it return previous page, but at same time it will exit the app. Just press the back button once, anyone can help me solve this problem.
Use V4 slide fragment.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);

    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`moveTaskToBack(true)` is the responsible for closing your app, if you only want your app to close when you are on the first page of your 'ViewPager' try moving it inside the if statement.

Something like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    } else {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to call the app back, what should I do ?

Comment: All the time? Or just when you are on the first page?

Comment: At first page, I want to this app running in background, not exit.

Comment: If the fragment stack has no previous page, this app should running in background, that is why I need TashToback(). if stack not empty, it should return previous page.Thx

Answer (score 0):

You need use [`addToBackStack`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

```
public void showFragment(View v) {
FragmentA f = new FragmentA();

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, f, tag);
ft.addToBackStack(tag);
ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this way before, but it does not work, because it is slide fragment, can not use replace~~~only use setCurrentItem(i) can change page, but it likes press twice, to previous page and exit

Answer (score 0):

try this at `Activity`:

```
System.exit(1);
```

or at other classes you can use this:

```
context.System.exit(1);
```